# How does predict_proba work with cross-validation?

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation, caret

When using 5-fold cross-validation to create a model, 5 different models are created. The selection of the final model can vary:

1. best-estimated (or other criteria) model out of the 5-fold created model or
2. the model create when trained on all the datasets.

I understand that cross-validation is used for model checking, not for model building. So when a `predict_proba` is used on the model, how is this probability defined? Could you share some papers or articles that talk about how the prediction works on caret in R and in `sklearn` in Python with cross-validation?

Answer (score 0):

The [docs for `sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict.html) make it clear that you can specify the prediction method with the `method` argument, e.g. `method='predict_proba'`.

If you do this, it simply calls that method internally instead of `predict`. The result is an estimate of the target made **when each fold was the validation set** during cross-validation.

For what it's worth, I would not select the model from the best-scoring CV fold. Train the final model on all your data.